# How can I make sure that my twitch bot can only take commands from certain users with NODEJS and the TMI API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitch, twitch-api

I am trying to make a twitch bot that uses a command that only the channel owner can use. How can I identify a unique user. Basically, how can I tell the program to only allow a certain user to use a certain command?

Comment: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication/

Comment: thanks but I went for something a little bit more simple. :)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my issue using the following: `${user['display-name']}` 
then applied this to a variable and used an if statement. 
Like this

```
    var chanName = '${user['display-name']}`;
    if (chanName === 'usernameperson`){
       stuff;
}
```